# Sharepoint calendar Webpart is not switching months in IE

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, calendar

I am using a SharePoint page in which a SharePoint calendar  is added as a webpart. The same page is displayed in a iframe tab using html code.I referred the same html code as as content editor webpart in another page.But the problem is that calendar is not switching months in IE while clicking on next and previous month button.on click its opening a new tab and giving message as "IE cannot display page"
The html  code is working fine.but when its referred in the content editor webpart ,the calendar is not switching months.The issue is only in IE.but in chrome its working fine.
Please help !!!

Comment: So to be clear, you have a Content Editor web part which contains HTML to show an iframe; the iframe is itself exposing a different page in SharePoint that has a calendar web part on it, and that calendar web part is not functioning correctly when displayed within the iframe. Is that right?

Comment: The Same is working in chrome.But in ie when i click on next button on calendar its opening in new tab with  url as  javascript:MoveToDate('11\u002f14\u002f2015','WPQ3');  and displaying message as page cannot be displayed